# How to put multiple variables in one vector?

Tags: r, vector

I want to put multiple types of variables like integer & character in one single vector in R script. So far I can put single type of variable in a vector, like I can make one vector with only integers or only characters. I also put integer & double in a single vector & it is testified in `#is.double()` as true. If I put integer, double & character, all 3 in a single vector, it is testified in `#is.character()` as true. I mean why not it is testified as integer of character?  The fact is more like, with multiple variables in a single vector, 1st character supersedes all, then double. Why this is like this way?

## this is a vector of integers.

```
w <- c(12, 22, 23, 33, 55)
```

## this is a character vector

```
w1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

## this I tried to put integer, double & character combined. But if I run it it shows as a character vector

```
w2 <- c(44, "b2", 33, 43L)
```

Comment: You can't - as you've found out the values get coerced to a higher level in the order `character > complex > numeric > integer > logical > raw` . You can however use a `list` if you want - `list(1, "a", 43L)`

Comment: What's your use-case for this behavior? @thelatemail is correct that this can't be done with vectors, but can with lists.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks a lot. I just applied and it works like this way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But now I created a vector using list and the elements of vectors cannot b tested using ##is.integer() or ##is.double(), all tests are stated as false in console. Can u please explain this? @thelatemail. Thanks.

Comment: @ShishirHossain - you have to loop over your created `list` - try `sapply(listname, is.integer)`

Comment: It really works, thanks @thelatemail. Thanks a lot